# a MYSQL script to convert the column names to uppercase

Tags: mysql, regex, bash, sed

This is the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612338/a-mysql-script-to-convert-the-column-names-to-lowercase).

I am migrating from a `lowercase_names` db server to a case sensitive setup in which I require UPPER CASE names for tables and column (they are stored uppercase in code).

I have read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149850/471213) that using sed is a good way to replace names to lower case, which is not what I want.

So starting from the regex

```
s/`\(\w\+\)`/\L&/g
```

I changed it to

```
s/`\(\w\+\)`/\U&/g
```

Thinking that it would convert to upper case. Then I tried to run this one-liner after having imported the uppercase DDL

```
mysqldump --skip-triggers --compact --no-create-info -hxx -uxx -pxx source | sed s/`\(\w\+\)`/\U&/g | mysql -hxx -uxx -pxx target
```

But that failed

```
-bash: /g: No such file or directory
-bash: (w+): command not found
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command
```

How can I run this uppercase-converter in Bash?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single quotes around your sed command, otherwise some of the parts will be interpreted by the shell:

```
mysqldump ... | sed 's/`\(\w\+\)`/\U&/g'
```

In case you're interested, the `&` is interpreted as an instruction to run the command in the background (so `/g` is processed as a separate command) and the backticks create a subshell. Escaping the parentheses means that they are interpreted literally. Escaping `\w` and `\+` has no effect in this context, so the command `(w+)` is run.

As you're using `&` in the replacement string to get the full matched patttern rather than a specific capture group (e.g. `\1`), you can also remove the parentheses [as pointed out by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411506/a-mysql-script-to-convert-the-column-names-to-uppercase#comment45156648_28411542):

```
mysqldump ... | sed 's/`\w\+`/\U&/g'
```

In response to your concerns about other data being affected, it's a pretty broad regex (captures any word characters within backticks) so could apply to a lot of things. Depending on the size of your data, you might like to use `` sed -n 's/`\w\+`/\U&/gp' `` which will show you the parts that are being affected by the substitution. Using that information you could possibly change your regex. However, it's likely that there are better ways to do what you want in SQL itself.

Comment: Hahahahahahahahaha. Really trivial! Works great now!

Comment: And you don't need to use capturing group.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it the Shellshock exploits used such parentheses syntax

Comment: Could the sed damage geolocation data? I found an error " Column count doesn't match value count at row 42". Meanwhile I'll dump the DML to a file to check the exact line

Comment: @djechelon responded in my answer

Comment: Altering the information_schema is risky when your db features foreign keys, views and routines. We did a tremendous mistake by the first time we migrated from lowercase=0 to lowercase=1 (you understand I'm migrating from lowercase=1 to lowercase=0)